# What is the purpose of junit:junit in android studio

Tags: android, junit

Whenever I make a new android studio project, a library called junit:junit is always added into my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})


testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Is this library really necessary or does it just make my app heavier?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain on-topic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on the subject in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/), especially knowing that vast majority of newbies', usually elementary, questions has already been answered many times.

Answer (score 0):

It is library for testing your applications. You can read more  [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html#junit)

Answer (score 0):

It's a library to test your current application's methods, functionalities with given parameters and expected results. So you don't need to run manually the app, setting breakpoints, then click on 123894 buttons to see a result. It's for testing and debugging purpose.